# Parse Android query for objects created within month

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-parsequeryadapter, parse-android-sdk

I wanted to query object within December but it return with Jan-Nov object. This is my query.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
Date date = calendar.getTime();

Log.d("date", String.valueOf(date));
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Post");
query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", date);
query.count();

List<ParseObject> results = null;
results.size(); //this count include the whole year value
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but you should use CALENDAR.JANUARY rather than 0.

Answer (score 1):

First of all try this :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
```

You need to fetch all data for just 1 year ( Year start Jan 1 and end  Dec 31 ) and not more.And maybe that's the reason it stack there.

Also you don't need than line of code :

```
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Try just this :

```
query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", calendar.getTime());
```

I hope it help you.